# Bootstrap 5 nav-bar icon wont right justify

Tags: html, css

New to the forum, for personal interest I am doing a full stack dev course, early days, having an issue with a nav bar that I have run out of ideas for and wondered if anyone could help.

When the nav-bar collapses, the collapse icon always appears on the left of screen, next to the brand. I want this to appear on the right.

My nav-bar code is below

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
        <!--<span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"> -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span><img src="images/ABC Logo.jpg" height="30" width="50" pad="15"></span>  ABC Childcare</a>
        <div class="W-100 text-right">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
      </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Our Settings
              </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Culcheth</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cobbs Infants</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Broomfields Junior</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Meadowbank Primary</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ST Michaels</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Boothstown Methodist Primary</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ince Community Centre</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ince Childrens Centre</a></li>

                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ramsbotton</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link"  href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried various things such as float-xs-justify, ms-auto and me-auto, in relation to the button but nothing seems to make a difference. I used a lot of code from various websites and then tweaked it a bit for my purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` bootstrap class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```